# Datos vacios en POSTGRESQL

Tags: php, html, postgresql

Buen día camaradas fijense que tengo un formulario de registro en PHP y HTML conectado a una DB en POSTGRESQL pero tengo un problema que al enviar los datos me aparece el mensaje que los datos se agregaron correctamente pero al hacer la consulta select *from en la DB me aparacen los datos insertados vacios. Pueden ayudarme por favor.

Este es código de mi formulario de registro:

```html
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" 
    integrity="sha384-Vkoo8x4CGsO3+Hhxv8T/Q5PaXtkKtu6ug5TOeNV6gBiFeWPGFN9MuhOf23Q9Ifjh" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../Estilo.php">
    <title>Registrarse</title>
</head>
<body>
            
    <form action="./conexion/guardar.php">
        <h1>INGRESE SUS DATOS PARA REGISTRARSE</h1>
        <label for="usuario">Usuario:</label><br>
        <input type="text" name="usuario" placeholder="Eliga su nombre de usuario" size="25" required autofocus><br>
        <label for="clave1">Contraseña:</label><br>
        <input type="password" name='clave1' placeholder="Digite su clave" size="25" required autofocus pattern="{6,20}" oninvalid="alert('La contraseña debe tener más de 6 letras.')"><br>
        <button type="submit">Registrarse</button>
    </form>

    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.slim.min.js" 
    integrity="sha384-J6qa4849blE2+poT4WnyKhv5vZF5SrPo0iEjwBvKU7imGFAV0wwj1yYfoRSJoZ+n" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js" 
    integrity="sha384-Q6E9RHvbIyZFJoft+2mJbHaEWldlvI9IOYy5n3zV9zzTtmI3UksdQRVvoxMfooAo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" 
    integrity="sha384-wfSDF2E50Y2D1uUdj0O3uMBJnjuUD4Ih7YwaYd1iqfktj0Uod8GCExl3Og8ifwB6" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Y este es el documento del envio de datos:

```
<?php
require 'conexion.php';


if(isset($_POST['nombre_usuario']) || isset($_POST['contra_usuario']) || isset($_POST['usuario']) || isset($_POST['clave1'])  ){
$usuario = $_POST['nombre_usuario'];
$clave1 = $_POST['contra_usuario'];
}

$usuario =  ( empty($_POST['nombre_usuario'])) ? NULL : $_POST['nombre_usuario'];
$clave1 = (empty($_POST['contra_usuario'])) ? NULL : $_POST['contra_usuario'];

$insertar = "INSERT INTO usuarios (nombre_usuario, contra_usuario) VALUES ('$usuario','$clave1')";

$envio = pg_query($dbconn,$insertar);

    if($envio){
        echo "Datos agregados correctamente";
    }else{
        echo "Datos incorrectos";
    }
```

?>

Answer (score 1):

El método GET viene por default en los `form` de HTML, a menos que le indiques lo contrario, lo tomará así.

Por los que tus variables estarán en `$_GET` en vez de en `$_POST`

cuando tú hacías esto

```
$usuario =  ( empty($_POST['nombre_usuario'])) ? NULL : $_POST['nombre_usuario'];
```

Le estabas diciendo que si `empty($_POST['nombre_usuario'])`, es decir que si existe la variable y además está vacía, en ese caso no existía y por eso tomaba el primer valor del if ternario, que es `NULL`

Para solucionarlo simplemente agrega el `method="POST"` a tu `form`

```
<form action="./conexion/guardar.php" method="POST">
        <h1>INGRESE SUS DATOS PARA REGISTRARSE</h1>
        <label for="usuario">Usuario:</label><br>
        <input type="text" name="usuario" placeholder="Eliga su nombre de usuario" size="25" required autofocus><br>
        <label for="clave1">Contraseña:</label><br>
        <input type="password" name='clave1' placeholder="Digite su clave" size="25" required autofocus pattern="{6,20}" oninvalid="alert('La contraseña debe tener más de 6 letras.')"><br>
        <button type="submit">Registrarse</button>
    </form>
```

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu respuesta no me había dado cuenta de ese problema. Pero ya agregue el metodo POST y me sigue enviando datos vacios a la DB. No sé que tipo de problema tengo en el codigo de envío.

Comment: Has un print a `$_POST` en tu archivo php, edita tu pregunta y pon lo que te arroja